Cyclodextrins: Is there really a hydrophobic interior and hydrophilic exterior?
I do not get most of the explanations on why cyclodextrins are so good at hosting hydrophobic molecules. It is true that the hydroxyl groups are pointed outwards and thus the cavity is definitely less hydrophilic than it could be. But if I look at the MEP using programs like molview (https://molview.org/?cid=444041), I only see a very small ring inside that is green and thus not polar.
So what is actually the effect of this ring? Does it make the cavity actually quite hydrophobic or does it only make it sufficiently less hydrophilic so that it is just so able to host some hydrophobic molecules?
And why is it the whole exterior that is always described as hydrophilic? In molview, it seems that on the outside the green ring is also there, so it should only be the top and bottom that is hydrophilic, shouldn't it? Below, you find a few pictures that hopefully explain my confusion.





Some of the questions are addressed in this theoretical study.

Thanks for the link, but it confuses me even more. It is well established that water can also be hosted inside the cavity, so how can benzene be hosted just as well? It just does not make any sense to me.

Supramolecular chemistry texts (Ariga/Kunitake, Sect. 2.7) have outlined that the hydroxyls are both on the narrow face and the wider face, leaving the internal cavity wall mainly consisting of C-C and C-H bonds. The water 'hosting' appears to be strongest at the narrow side, but primarily stabilized by water-water H-bonding, not primarily because of water-wall interactions. When a guest (hydrophobic) is in aqueous solution, the displacement of water by the guest is more favorable.

Thank you, that makes sense. However, I still am a bit confused. You mention the C-C and C-H bonds, but there are also many ethyl groups pointing inwards, which may be not particularly hydrophilic, but definitely also not hydrophobic. So for me it would make more sense for the benzene molecules to just form a separate highly hydrophobic phase instead of sorrounding themselves with partly polar ether groups inside of the cyclodextrin molecules.

I think this might be one of those cases where a combination of factors (dispersion forces, dipole interactions, H-bonds, etc) between host-guest molecules results in complexation being favored. Many authors mention a high complimentarity between β-cyclodextrin and benzene (i.e., benzene fits into the cavity really well), and the study that Karsten linked shows similar concepts for other drugs, so I assume this has a major stabilizing effect. Complimentarity can be a big factor—it actually forms the basis for all HG interactions.

@Sonder I would encourage you to rewrite your comments in an answer. I think you covered most of it in the comments but these may go away while answers remain.

Thanks you, this definitely helped!

@Karsten Thanks, I have just done that. I have also included my sources.

Many supramolecular chemistry texts (1)(2) have described the structure of cyclodextrins. Most commonly used is the tapered cylinder model, which has a narrow face and a wide face, referred to as the primary and secondary faces, respectively. The primary face comprises the primary hydroxyl groups, and the secondary faces comprises the $\ce{—CH2OH}$, or the secondary hydroxyl groups. All hydroxyl groups are exocylic, leaving the internal cavity wall primarily made up of C-C and C-H bonds. It is this cavity, along with the exocylic hydroxyls, that allows for cyclodextrin to function the way it does, creating hydrophobic micro-domains within an aqueous solution, and polar domains which associate with water. The figure below should help visualize the structure better (taken from 3).

The cyclodextrins have been investigated for a long time, and many non-polar guests have been hosted to create simple inclusion complexes and rotaxanes with them. This is not to say that polar molecules cannot associate within the cavity of the cyclodextrins. In fact, as you rightly point out, hydrates of cyclodextrin most certainly exist. In an aqueous solution with no guest molecules, the inner cavity is filled with water molecules, which has been confirmed with diffraction and crystallization studies (4). The inner ring is majorly hydrophobic. It is just that polar molecules like water do not associate with the cyclodextrin cavity in the same way as non-polar molecules do.
The water 'hosting' appears to be strongest at the narrow side where electron density is highest, but primarily stabilized by water-water H-bonding, not primarily because of water-wall interactions (5). Non-polar molecules on the other hand, will associate through every kind of host-wall forces: dispersion, dipole, and H-bonding. The closer the size of the guest to the size of the host's cavity, the greater the number and strength of the interactions — an effect called complementarity, which forms the basis for all supramolecular chemistry. The effect of complementarity is profound, described by many authors (1)(2)(J. M. Lehn also emphasizes its importance in his lectures and books), also observed in the theoretical study that Karsten linked (7). This is the effect of the ring.

It is because these electron densities are high primarily at the rim that the inclusion of polar molecules like water is not particularly strong, as they do not have complete hydrogen bonding to all centers (see above; figure taken from (6)), nor are they particularly similar in size to that of the cavity (i.e., they have low complementarity). Thus, when an appropriately-sized non-polar molecule (for example, benzene) is also in aqueous solution, the displacement of the (relatively) loosely-bound water molecules and the inclusion of the non-polar guest occurs. The combination of interactions (dispersion forces, dipole interactions, H-bonds) and the effect of complementarity between host-guest molecules results in the complexation of non-polar substrates being favored in an aqueous solution.

Ariga, K., Kunitake, T.; Supramolecular Chemistry — Fundamentals and Applications, Sect. 2.7: Cyclodextrin – A Naturally Occurring Cyclic Host, Springer, 2006, pp. 21
Steed, J. W., Atwood, J. L.; Supramolecular Chemistry, Sect. 6.3: Cyclodextrins, 2nd Ed., Wiley, 2009.
Battle, C. H., Jayawickramarajah, J.; Supramolecular Approaches for Inhibition of Protein–Protein and Protein–DNA Interactions, Wiley, 2012.
Saenger, W. et al.; "Structures of the Common Cyclodextrins and Their Larger Analogues — Beyond the Doughnut." Chem. Rev., Vol. 98, Issue 5, 1998.
Pereva, S., Nikolova, V., Angelova, S., Spassov, T., Dudev, T.; Beilstein J. Org. Chem., Vol. 15, 2019.
Sandilya, A. A., Natarajan, U., Priya, M. H.; ACS Omega, Vol. 5, No. 40, 2020.
Chen, W., Chang, C. E., Gilson, M. K.; Biophys J., Vol. 87, No. 5, 2004.


you are incredible, thanks!
